# What is the Source of the Approximate "R Value" Chart?

Tags: insulation

There is a Chart labeled Approximate "R Value" of Walls, Windows, Ceiling & Floor in one of the responses to the question [How can I measure the r-value of a wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/22203/33) What is the source of this table?

[image]

Comment: Web search will find many versions of this, most commonly from companies which sell insulation-related products. Ultimately,  it comes from standardized measurement procedures.

Comment: Thanks keshlam. Do you know what organization developed these standardized measurement procedures and/or where I could find those measurement procedures?

Comment: There's an ASTM standards document covering this but I don't think they originated the measurement. Not sure who did. It's related fairly directly to the k- value and u-value measurements since they're all describing thermal conductivity but scaling it differently.

Comment: I've found it in this [publication: Journal of Civil Engineering Research
p-ISSN: 2163-2316    e-ISSN: 2163-2340
2014](http://article.sapub.org/10.5923.c.jce.201401.09.html#Sec2.7)

Answer (score 1):

[Journal of Civil Engineering Research

p-ISSN: 2163-2316    e-ISSN: 2163-2340

2014;  4(2A): 42-50

doi:10.5923/c.jce.201401.09](http://article.sapub.org/10.5923.c.jce.201401.09.html)

[PDF](http://www.sapub.org/global/showpaperpdf.aspx?doi=10.5923/c.jce.201401.09)

> To determine the "R value" of a wall, insulated window or ceiling
>   requires three simple temperature measurements:
>
> 1. The "air" or ambient room temperature.
> 2. The inside surface temperature of an exterior wall.
> 3. The outside surface temperature of the same exterior wall.
>
> The difference of the interior and exterior wall temperatures is
>   calculated and this is labeled as "Temperature Difference, Interior to
>   Exterior Wall". Now the difference between the "air" or ambient and
>   the interior wall temperature is taken and this is labeled as
>   "Temperature Difference, Air to Interior Wall". The interior to
>   exterior difference is taken and the corresponding point is selected
>   on the bottom of the graph given below. The air to interior difference
>   is selected on the vertical axis of graph. Curve is chosen from these
>   two points.

[image: Figure 14]

Answer (score 0):

[R-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-value_(insulation)) is actually a unit of measure for thermal resistance, just as meters are a unit of measure for length.

The physical property of an insulator's thermal resistance is quantified by the *ratio* of the *temperature difference* and the *heat transfer per unit area per unit time* (aka, heat flux).

So your units would be

- **Kelvin x Meters^2 / Watts** for SI units
- **Hours x Feet^2 x °Fahrenheit / British Thermal Units** for freedom units

Note there's a conversion factor of 5.678263 when going from Imperial to SI measurments.

Comment: This is true, but unlike length, heat flux is not so straightforward to measure. It requires an elaborate temperature-controlled environment on both sides of the insulation assembly to be tested. It's not like your Average Joe can whip out a measuring tape. Also, thermal resistance is not actually constant across all temperatures... fiberglass insulation is about 20% more effective at 32 ºF than at 100 ºF. And some types of rigid foam insulation get worse at colder temperatures, not better. So the testing procedure is important.

Comment: Wow, this is good. I learned something today.